# How to change the point type based on the data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot the stock market data in gnuplot. So my issue is that I want to plot a triangle pointing up in case I buy at the price and a triangle pointing down in case I sell at that price. But I am not sure how to pass a variable as argument to the pointtype keyword

```
10-06-2021 2729.05 1
09-06-2021 2766.20 0
08-06-2021 2765.00 1
07-06-2021 2750.25 1
04-06-2021 2767.45 0
03-06-2021 2680.20 -1
02-06-2021 2645.55 -1
01-06-2021 2610.00 1
31-05-2021 2638.45 -1
28-05-2021 2630.00 0
27-05-2021 2649.00 0
```

This is a sample file, in the third column 1 means a buy signal(which I want to represent as a up triangle) and the 0 means a sell signal(which I want to represent with a down triangle) and -1 indicates no buy/sell signal(which I want to represent as a circle)

Presently I am only plotting the stock price data using the below command

```
plot "demo.csv" using 1:2 with linespoints linecolor 11 pointtype 15
```

Comment: Have you checked the manual? In the gnuplot console type: `help pointtype variable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Additionally with varying color.
Please check `help pointtype variable`. If you want the line a single color, e.g. "black", you probably have to plot separately `with points` and `with lines`.

**Code:**

```
### variable pointtype and color
reset session

$Data <<EOD
10-06-2021 2729.05 1
09-06-2021 2766.20 0
08-06-2021 2765.00 1
07-06-2021 2750.25 1
04-06-2021 2767.45 0
03-06-2021 2680.20 -1
02-06-2021 2645.55 -1
01-06-2021 2610.00 1
31-05-2021 2638.45 -1
28-05-2021 2630.00 0
27-05-2021 2649.00 0
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%d-%m-%Y"
set format x "%d-%m\n%Y" time 
myPt(col)    = column(col)==1 ? 9 : column(col)==0 ? 11 : 7
myColor(col) = column(col)==1 ? 0x00ff00 : column(col)==0 ? 0xff0000 : 0xcccccc
unset key
set grid x,y

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2:(myPt(3)):(myColor(3)) w lp ps 3 pt var lc rgb var
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]